# How do I free an array in C inside a function that doesn't know if it is allocated on stack or heap?

Tags: c, malloc, free

Let's say in C I have implemented a function `B foo(const A arr[])`, where `A` and `B` are recursively dependent structs, potentially heavy dynamically allocated. Function `foo` creates `B` out of `A`s (basically copying them in some way into `B`) and also takes care of freeing some deeply recursed elements inside original `A`s  in input array. I cannot change that functionality.

Now let's say I also have a function `B bar(B *b1, B*b2)` that does some work and statically allocates array of `A`s out of `b1` and `b2` (of the length of `|b1| * |b2|` to be precise) and returns `foo(A)`. So far it all has worked well: `foo` has been freeing dynamically allocated elements of `A` with no leaks and as `arr` was not malloc'ed I didn't have to free `arr`.

But then I've come across a stress test for `bar` that triggers a stack overflow due to excessive size of array it creates on stack (well, at least that's my guess as Valgrind reported some 10^6+ strange errors like "Invalid write of size 8/Address 0xffe8625d0 is on thread 1's stack" but zero leaks). So I changed the way I define an array of `A` inside `bar` from static to dynamic.

Valgrind's strange errors disappeared, but leaks have come out as I don't know how to free this intrinsic array of `A` inside `bar` as `bar` calls `foo` which needs that array and moreover it takes responsibility for it so the problem is there are calls to `foo` with arrays allocated either on stack or on heap and I cannot outsource free'ing outside `foo`. That is a homework 'good C style' project and hacky tricks (like some direct grabs of heap/stacks at low level) should be avoided.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: It's really hard to follow like that. What about some code?

Comment: Can you not pass in a bool or something to say static or dynamic?  Or place that value in the struct passed around so that you know how to free it.

Comment: If the types are likely to get too large for the stack, why not just make the APIs only handle dynamically allocated memory (so ownership can be passed properly)? Otherwise, you're stuck with hacky tricks, or multiple APIs (one which passes top-level ownership, one which doesn't). Fundamentally, you can't transfer ownership of stack variables, and you can't contractually distinguish a raw pointer to stack from raw pointer to heap; trying to do so is doomed to failure. The OpenSSL BIGNUM APIs just define `new` vs. `init` and `free` vs. `destroy` APIs for top level on heap or stack.

Comment: The obvious (trivial) solution would be to free the block in `bar` (since `bar` allocates it) after it is no longer needed (after the call to `foo` and before the return from `bar`?).

Comment: One possible solution can be to switch to `std::unique_ptr<A[]>` probably.

Comment: @bipll: Not really an option for C code... :-) Now, if the OP wants to switch to C++, that becomes a possibility.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misread a tag.

Comment: Pass in a 'deallocate()' function pointer and have foo() call it?  If you cannot change the prototype of foo() at all, use a fooWrapper().

Comment: I cannot change the foo prototype at all so cannot pass anything extra. But I rearranged the code in a way Chris suggested and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Given just a pointer value, there is no portable/reliable way to determine if it was allocated by new, by `malloc()`, or if it even points to something on the heap (the pointer passed may actually point to an object on stack). It may even point to an element in an array. There's no way the function can tell.

You have to manage your memory yourself. If you have declared `A` dynamically, then you will HAVE to change `foo` accordingly.

Comment: Are you quoting something? If so, link it, otherwise, don't use blockquotes.

Comment: Thanks Liran, I solved my issue other way round but for educational purposes - not even a hacky way to determine that?